# What method to use for logout in wicket application?

Tags: java, wicket, httpsession

Wicket `org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession` has 2 methods: `signOut` and `invalidate`. The javac says that `signOut` mark use `not logged in` while `invalidate` do the same (e.g. call `signOut`) but

> remove the logon data from where ever they have been persisted

At first glace for logout action `signOut` should be called. But for [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) session **must** be invalidated immediately after user logins or logouts. So from this point `invalidate` should be called.

So what to call for logout? Also when it is needed to call `signOut` and when `invalidate`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to logout only, use AuthenticatedWebSession#signOut().

AuthenticatedWebSession uses an internal boolean flag 'signedIn' to notice if a user has been signed in (true) or no body has been ever signed in or a user has been logged out.

WebSession#invalidate() is responsible for removing session from the Wicket session registry and its complete invalidation. The implementation of AuthenticatedWebSession#invalidate() invokes AuthenticatedWebSession#signOut() as well, so that the regular log out is done. That could be helpful if your logout process requires some other action, so you can override AuthenticatedWebSession#signOut() method.

In other words:

- invalidate() calls signOut() and than removes the session from the session registry.
- signOut() marks the session as 'not signed in', but it does NOT remove the session.

Answer (score 0):

For logout you should use `#invalidate()`! In my opinion `#signOut()` should not be part of the API. At the best it should be an alias of `#invalidate()`.

If you want to be really secure then you should use `#replaceSession()` after login.