# Unable to sign out from wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm managing authentication by extending AuthenticatedWebSession

Signing in

```
@Override
protected boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    return true/false some auth logic here;
}
```

Sign out

```
@Override
    public void signOut() {
        super.signOut();
        this.getApplication().getSecuritySettings().getAuthenticationStrategy().remove();
        this.getSessionStore().invalidate(RequestCycle.get().getRequest());
        throw new RedirectToUrlException("some_url_that_does_not_require_auth", HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    }
```

And my page configuration

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("ADMIN")
public class Home extends Base {
  //Page stuff here
}
```

Now the problem is that if I log out I can still access authenticated content. Via clicking back button or pasting url to browser. I can only watch the content, when I click on something it redirect me to non-auth page.

When signing out session id changes and session is removed from SecuritySettings, can't figure it out why it still shows auth content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `session.invalidate()` instead of `session.signOut()`.

I'll suggest to remove/hide `signOut()` from the API for Wicket 8.x. Recently someone else had the same problem ([What method to use for logout in wicket application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38710916/497381)).

Comment: Same happens when I call `AuthWebSession.get().invalidate();`

Comment: Sorry I still had residue left from signOut, invalidate work well.